# Jquery animation with an if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Basically what I've made is a panorama shot and then put it into a div called Screen (which is also inside another div called Screen 1 making it so only a 600x400px portion can be seen at any time), and then made a function for the left arrow to when clicked to move the Screen div 200px across. It works fine at the moment, even though my code is probably not very clean.
But anyway my problem is that i am trying to make an if statement so that when the left position of the div reaches a certain amount the arrow hides, but it will not work whatever i try.
Here is the code below:

Click function:

```
$('#arrowl').click(function() {
    $('#Screen').animate({
        left: '+=200'
    }, 300, function() {
        duration: 200,
        movescreen();
    });
});
```

movescreen function:

```
var a = $('#Screen').css("left")

function movescreen () {
    if( a == "-5px") {
        alert("success")
    }
}
```

Ive also tried using position rather than the css tag, but didnt help at all. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. I've been scratching my head for hours now.

Comment: assuming your missing semicolons are typos, i see nothing terribly wrong with that.  what does `a` equal, and why are you getting it outside of your function?

Comment: Actually, semicolons aren't strictly necessary in JavaScript; EOL is enough. They're considered standard though.

Comment: a should be = to the left value of the div screen. However whenever i run an alert for it in the movescreen function it just returns the same number -1405px (its starting position). =/

Answer (score 0):

I am operating under the assumption that the -5px position is the position where you want to hide the arrow. The issue is that you're evaluating the position before the point where you care, and it's changing. You need to do the evaluation *inside* the movescreen function:

```
function movescreen() {
    if ($('#Screen').css('left') === '-5px') {
        window.alert('success');
    }
}
```

That said, I'm having a rough time assessing whether that's the only problem you're having. I recommend trying more intensive debugging -- but that's the obvious error I can see.

Comment: Yeah i managed to debug it to a degree and this is basically what i have been able to scope from it:
That the function works, however the problem lies in that the left value for the image isn't changing. When i tell the statement to run when the left position is equal to -1405 (its starting position) it runs every time i press the arrow. And upon inspecting the elements in chrome, i can clearly see the left value changing, so I am currently completely out of ideas =/